# Solving an equation of one unknown, given as a function

Tags: algorithm, matlab, equation-solving

I have a homework assignment and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I'm given everything except `r`.  I need to use this formula, as it's saved as a function from a previous exercise. The function is:

```
function t = annuitet( g , T , G , r , n )
%Et annuitetslån
%g  termingebyr på kr for hvert terminforfall
%T  annuitetslån på kr
%G  etablerings gebyr
%r  årlig rente
%n  antall terminer (=antall år ganger 12)

t = g + ((T+G)*((r/12)/100))/(1-(1+(r/12)/100)^(-n*12));

end
```

Don't mind that it's in Norwegian.

I am given that:

```
T = 2000000
n = 20
G = 3000
g = 50
t = 9500
```

I know that `r` has to be 1.26%, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to manipulate this in order to make a script that will make it work.

Currently have:

```
T = input('Tast inn lånebeløp (kr):');
n = input('Løpetid (år):');
G = input('Etableringsgebyr (kr):');
g = input('Termingebyr (kr):');

disp('Absolutt minste terminbeløp (Rente = 0 %): 8396 kr');
t = input('Tast inn terminbeløpet du kan klare (kr):');
```

Thanks in advance for any hints/tips :)

Comment: -1 because you didn't make an attempt, you didn't bother to translate the comments and/or remove the unnecessary parts. The "Currently I have" bit is completely irrelevant to the question at hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve an equation with 1 unknown. The way to go about this numerically, is define an equation for the residual (that is "how bad is my error given some guess for `r`") and then try to minimize said residual.

One way to do this is using [`fzero`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html). Another way is by guessing `r` using some fine grid (e.g. `0.001:0.001:100`) and looking which `r` gives you the lowest residual. Yet another way is by doing the former, and plotting it (a "graphical solution" of sorts).

Since this is a homework assignment, I'm putting the rest of the solution as  "hidden" text. I encourage you to read the documentation and try to figure it out on your own, then when you succeed, compare it with my answer :)

Good luck!

> `r_sol = fzero(@(r)t-annuitet( g , T , G , r , n ), 1000);` 
> `-> r_sol = 1.264530947561246`

Comment: Great answer, lots of help.  Thanks!